# Android - Parse.com Populating Array from ONE element

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I am trying to populate an Array from a parse.com query and I am stock in the part of getting the element from query. basically i dont know where to get the current location for exercise_object.get(location) thanks.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Programs");
    query.whereEqualTo("name", objname);
    query.orderByAscending("name");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //success
                String [] exercice = new String[3];
                exercise_object = list;
                Toast.makeText(Wko_Display.this, "Workouts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ParseObject program_object = exercise_object.get(location);
                exercice [0] = exercise_object.getString("wk0");
                exercice [1] = exercise_object.getString("wk1");
                exercice [2] = exercise_object.getString("wk2");


            }
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you're trying to do/need help with. Can you clarify?

Comment: Trying to populate a string array from a parse object that I am getting from parse.com the problem is that I am getting the whole parse list and I want to go object by object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then this should work:

```
@Override
public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e){
    if (e == null){
        for (ParseObject pObj : list){
            String[] exercise = new String[3];
            // assuming each ParseObject has a pointer to a Program object in the database
            ParseObject programObject = pObj.getParseObject("location");
            // do whatever you want with this programObject

            // then do any further stuff with the current pObj in the list
            exercise[0] = pObj.getString("wk0");
            // ...

        }
    } else{
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

This would be wrong if you're expecting only one object to be returned from the query though. Let me know.